# Горизонтальное меню

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать горизонтальное меню в стилях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или же в `CSS` для того самого списка <ul><li></li></ul>:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
li {
   display: inline;
   margin-right: 20px;
}

li:last-of-type {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не совсем понятен. Но если имеется в виду меню под хедером.
То в html пишешь список

```
<ul>  
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

(Без скобок) где li название пунктов меню. Первому ul назначаешь класс.

Сам класс описываешь в таблице стилей и задаешь для начала

```
.class{float:left; list-style:none;}  
.class li {padding: 10px 20px;}
```

`float:left` --выравнивание по левой стороне пунктов меню, и тд. Постепенно прописываешь своему меню все остальные параметры цвет, шрифт и тд. [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css) -- тут неплохой справочник по CSS.